# Файл конфигурации logstash

Tags: logstash

Всем привет, подскажите будет ли корректен данный код:

```
if [type] == "" or [type] == "" or [type] == ""
```

Если нет, то какие операторы перечисления можно использовать в данном случае, в блоке if есть одна проверка для всех объектов с тегом type, объект выглядит вот так

```
file {
type => "runstatus12"
path => "C:/BuildAgent2/work/baef4ea7e758f5b8/dms-selenium-tests/TestSelenium/bin/Debug/runStatus.log"
mode => "tail"
start_position => "beginning"
codec => plain { charset => "Windows-1251" }
sincedb_path => "nul"}
```

заранее спасибо
весь код файла выглядит таким образом:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    user => "logstash_internal"
    password => "12341234"
  }
  file {
    type => "pikautotesttc"
    path => "C:/BuildAgent/work/baef4ea7e758f5b8/dms-selenium-tests/TestSelenium/bin/Debug/Logs/**/*.log*"
    mode => "tail"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => plain { charset => "Windows-1251" }
    sincedb_path => "nul"
  }
  file {
    type => "runstatus"
    path => "C:/BuildAgent/work/baef4ea7e758f5b8/dms-selenium-tests/TestSelenium/bin/Debug/runStatus.log"
    mode => "tail"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => plain { charset => "Windows-1251" }
    sincedb_path => "nul"
  }
  file {
    type => "pikautotesttc12"
    path => "C:/BuildAgent2/work/baef4ea7e758f5b8/dms-selenium-tests/TestSelenium/bin/Debug/Logs/**/*.log*"
    mode => "tail"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => plain { charset => "Windows-1251" }
    sincedb_path => "nul"
  }
  file {
    type => "runstatus12"
    path => "C:/BuildAgent2/work/baef4ea7e758f5b8/dms-selenium-tests/TestSelenium/bin/Debug/runStatus.log"
    mode => "tail"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => plain { charset => "Windows-1251" }
    sincedb_path => "nul"
  }
}

filter {
  elasticsearch {
    user => "logstash_internal"
    password => "12341234"
  }
  fingerprint {
    source => "message"
    target => "[@metadata][fingerprint]"
    method => "MD5"
    key => "pik"
  }
  if [type] == "runstatus" or [type] == "runstatus12" 
  {
    grok {
        match => {
        "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:date}\s+%{WORD:loglevel}\s+(\[\d+\])?\s+:\s*Сценарий - (?<scenario>.*?)(?=\;)\;\sссылка на контракт - (?<positionUrl>.*)(?=\;)\; попытка \((?<attempt>\d)\/5\) - (?<status>.*)(?=\;)\;\s?(?<screenshot>(.*)?)"
        }
      }
      date {
      match => ["date", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
  }
  if [type] == "pikautotesttc" or [type] == "pikautotesttc12"
  {
      if "URL:" in [message]
    {
      grok {
        match => {
        "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:logdate}\s+%{WORD:loglevel}\s+(\[\d+\])?\s+:\s*%{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}(?= URL: )?( URL: )%{GREEDYDATA:url}(?=\.)\.( User: )?%{GREEDYDATA:user}"
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
     grok {
        match => {
          "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:logdate}\s+%{WORD:loglevel}\s+(\[\d+\])?\s+:\s*%{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}"
        }
      }
    }
    grok {
      match => { 
        "msgbody" => [
          "Test (?<status>[^&]*)",
          "Время выполнения (контракта|теста) \(первая попытка\): (?<duration>\d+.\d+)"
        ]
      }
      match => {
        "path" => "log\.?(?<attempt>\d)"
      }
      break_on_match => false
    }
    date {
      match => ["logdate", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
    mutate {
      convert => {
        "duration" => "float"
      }
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    manage_template => true
    index => "logstash-%{type}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
    user => "logstash_internal"
    password => "12341234"
  }
}
```

Comment: странный какой-то json. В каком языке надо проверить? js? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: это json для logstash, там есть 3 блока input, filter, output, вот хотелось бы понимать могу ли я несколько объектов запихнуть в одну проверку... уже голову поломал всю

Comment: я могу весь код в вопрос положить

Comment: Это формат конфига конкретно logstash, к json он никакого отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл сформирован корректно, дело в том, что когда ElasticSearch пытался принять данный файл конфигурации, ему не хватало прав, чтобы сделать еще несколько индексов по разным директориям, необходимо было зайти в Kibana => настройки => роли пользователя => выполнить настройку в разделе Logstash Writer, ошибки вы можете посмотреть в папке Logstash => Logs